# Does dropping a Postgres table cascade to materialized views that depend on it?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-view, cascade

I understand that a regular view will be invalid if a table it is dependent on is dropped.

Does the same apply to a materialized view?

I would assume that in a materialized view since the data has been decoupled from the source table, it should be possible to drop the table, but warn or abort if an attempt is made to recreate or refresh the view.

In short can a materialized view be decoupled from its source tables so long as there is no attempt to recreate it?

Comment: It's probably very easy to test; have you tried that?

Comment: Data from other tables can be added and removed from the view and as the view is always in use, dropping some the tables would impact on it. I think I will truncate the source tables rather than drop them or export the materialized view to a separate table and use that instead.
I was wondering whether Postgres had a built-in way of dealing with this kind of situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two distinct questions:

> Does dropping a Postgres table cascade to materialized views that depend on it?

**No**, it raises an exception. Unless you add the keyword [`CASCADE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-droptable.html#id-1.9.3.134.6). Then **yes**. (Same as with regular views.)

```
DROP TABLE tbl CASCADE;
```

> Can a materialized view be decoupled from its source tables?

**No**, there is no way. You might try to manipulate catalog tables as superuser manually. But don't go there.

Answer (score 1):

"I understand that a regular view will be invalid if a table it is dependent on is dropped."

No, you misunderstand. It's true for some other RDBMS, but not for PostgreSQL.

PostgreSQL won't let you drop a table if there is a view dependent on it.

Generally, PostgreSQL won't let you drop anything if there is another object dependent on it.